# crontab fails to write logs

Tags: cron, django

I'm using crontab to run a python script every minute. This is my how my crontab file looks like:

```
*/1 * * * *  source /root/.bashrc && source /home/env/bin/activate && python /home/manage.py shell < /home/script.py  >> /var/log/navjob.log 2>&1
```

When try to check cron output in syslog with this command `#grep CRON /var/log/syslog` the output is like this:

```
...CRON[764888]: (root) CMD (source /root/.bashrc && source /home/env/bin/activate && python /home/manage.py shell < /home/script.py  >> /var/log/navjob.log 2>&1)
...CRON[764887]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

But the log file (/var/log/navjob.log) is empty and the code is not run!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you chain commands and add redirection like

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 >> somefile 2>&1
```

(or `cmd1 ; cmd2 ; cmd3 >> somefile 2>&1` etc.) the redirections only apply to the last command in the chain. To redirect all of them, you need to group the commands like

```
{ cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 ; } >> somefile 2>&1
```

or (with a subshell)

```
( cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 ) >> somefile 2>&1
```

In this case, your cron job is likely failing at the very first `source` command, since `source` is a bashism and cron's default shell is `/bin/sh` - either add `SHELL=/bin/bash` before the crontab entry, or change `source` to the POSIX `.`

Comment: `:facepalm:` for the `SHELL=/bin/bash` . That is what fixed it for me.